# IndexOutofBoundException at getChildView() in expandableListView

Tags: android, indexing, arraylist, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am adding three child objects with name of All Homes All plots and All Commercial and i do it on run time i add these three objects with three parents that are Homes Plots and Commercial so in other terms i am adding three more categories in my Parents as child.i have done with it as whenever i load my expandableListview it loads the child on 0 index of my arrays but whenever i try to click on these newly created objects i get indexoutofboundexception error at method getChildView() as IndexOutOfBoundException invalid index 7 size is 7 and debugger show this error when i click on the child data is populated and when i navaigate back it shows this indexoutofBoundException Error at this method.
**My Modified Code is**

```
private void displayListListView(){
    final ExpandableListView listview = (ExpandableListView)mView. findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    final ExpendableAdapter expendableAdapter = new ExpendableAdapter();
    //ArrayList<PropertyParent> childs = new ArrayList<PropertyParent>();
    //PropertyParent parent =   new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();
    PropertyTypeInfo property = new PropertyTypeInfo();

    for(int i=0;i<Utils.propertyTypesList.size();i++)
    {
    //  if( Utils.propertyTypesList.size()>0)
        //{

        property = Utils.propertyTypesList.get(i);
        //if(property.getParentId()=="1" && property!=null){
        if(parent==null)
        {


             parent =   new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

            parent.setTypeId("9,8,21,22,20,24,25");
            parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
            parent.setTitleAlt2("All Houses");
            parent.setParentId("1");
            parent.setTitleAlt1("All House");
            childs= property.getChilds();
            childs.add(0, parent);
            }
        //}

            else if(parent.getTypeId()=="9,8,21,22,20,24,25"){
                parent =    new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

                parent.setTypeId("12,23,11,19,26,27");
                parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
                parent.setTitleAlt2("All Plots");
                parent.setParentId("2");
                parent.setTitleAlt1("Residential Plot");
                childs= property.getChilds();
                childs.add(0, parent);

            }

            else if(parent.getTypeId()== "12,23,11,19,26,27")
            {
                parent =    new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

                parent.setTypeId("13,15,17,14,16,18");
                parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
                parent.setTitleAlt2("All Commercial");
                parent.setParentId("3");
                parent.setTitleAlt1("Commercial");
                childs= property.getChilds();
                childs.add(0,parent);



            }

        //else
        //{




        //}





    }
//  }

    expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listview.setAdapter(expendableAdapter);
    //expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
```

**and my getChildView Method is**

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_item, parent, false);
        }
        RadioButton rbSelect = (RadioButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rbSelect.setText(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition).getTitle());
        if(selectedIndexChild == childPosition && selectedIndexParent == groupPosition){
            rbSelect.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            rbSelect.setChecked(false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My Data in Json is

```
 "meta": {
    "status": "200",
    "mesaage": "Data Successfully Retrieved"
  },
  "response": {
    "type": [
      {
        "type_id": "1",
        "title": "Homes",
        "title_alt2": "Homes",
        "parent_id": "",
        "title_alt1": "Home",
        "child_list": "9,8,21,22,20,24,25",
        "childs": [
          {
            "type_id": "9,8,21,22,20,24,25",
            "title": "All Homes",
            "title_alt2": "All  Houses",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "All House"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "9",
            "title": "Houses",
            "title_alt2": "Houses",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "House"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "8",
            "title": "Flats",
            "title_alt2": "Flats & Apartments",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Flat"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "21",
            "title": "Upper Portions",
            "title_alt2": "Upper Portions",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Upper Portion"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "22",
            "title": "Lower Portions",
            "title_alt2": "Lower Portions",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Lower Portion"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "20",
            "title": "Farm Houses",
            "title_alt2": "Farm Houses",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Farm House"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "24",
            "title": "Rooms",
            "title_alt2": "Rooms",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Room"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "25",
            "title": "Penthouse",
            "title_alt2": "Penthouse",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title_alt1": "Penthouse"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type_id": "2",
        "title": "Plots",
        "title_alt2": "Plots",
        "parent_id": "",
        "title_alt1": "Plot",
        "child_list": "12,23,11,19,26,27",
        "childs": [
          {
            "type_id": "12,23,11,19,26,27",
            "title": "All Plots",
            "title_alt2": "All Plots",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Residential Plot"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "12",
            "title": "Residential Plots",
            "title_alt2": "Plots",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Residential Plot"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "23",
            "title": "Plot Files",
            "title_alt2": "Plots",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Plot File"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "11",
            "title": "Commercial Plots",
            "title_alt2": "Commercial Plots",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Commercial Plot"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "19",
            "title": "Agricultural Land",
            "title_alt2": "Agricultural Land",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Agricultural Land"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "26",
            "title": "Plot Forms",
            "title_alt2": "Plot Forms",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Plot Form"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "27",
            "title": "Industrial Land",
            "title_alt2": "Industrial Land",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "title_alt1": "Industrial Land"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type_id": "3",
        "title": "Commercial",
        "title_alt2": "Commercial",
        "parent_id": "",
        "title_alt1": "Commercial Property",
        "child_list": "13,15,17,14,16,18",
        "childs": [
          {
            "type_id": "13",
            "title": "Offices",
            "title_alt2": "Offices",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Office"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "15",
            "title": "Shops",
            "title_alt2": "Shops",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Shop"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "17",
            "title": "Warehouses",
            "title_alt2": "Warehouses",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Warehouse"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "14",
            "title": "Factories",
            "title_alt2": "Factories",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Factory"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "16",
            "title": "Buildings",
            "title_alt2": "Buildings",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Building"
          },
          {
            "type_id": "18",
            "title": "Other",
            "title_alt2": "Other",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "title_alt1": "Other"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: parent.getTypeId()=="9,8,21,22,20,24,25". Replace == with .equals.    Also, why are you adding parent to your childList?

Comment: @carnal where i work they are already fetching data from url based upon the webservices but now they want to hard code the three categories All homes,All Plots,All Commercial so that in All Homes all Home child's come and in All Plots plots child come and in future if they want to add another functionality they could hard code it to get results without changing in their API.

Comment: Again it comes  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7   at fragments.Types$ExpendableAdapter.getChildView(Types.java:254)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your loop size

you have to loop condition look like this..

for(int i=0;i< Utils.propertyTypesList.size()-1;i++)

**Size -1**

Comment: if i make it Utils.propertyTypesList.size()-1 then array would not traverse properly like it would go till 0 and 1 index and would leave the 2 index hence only all homes all plots would be display but error is still there that is when after populating data while clicking on the radio button i come bak indexoutofbound exception error comes and app crashes